# Wordpress Redirection not working

Tags: wordpress, website, domain-name, redirection

I have a wordpress website where i applied a redirection with the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

I set a few 301 redirections but i get the following error:

This page isn’t redirecting properly
www.domain.com redirected you too many times.

I was wondering if any of you have a suggestion or know how to resolve to this issue. All propositions are welcome !

Thank you in advance

Comment: What was the redirection that you set up?

Comment: Very simple one, i used a "URL only" hank you for your input !
The redirects were very simple ones, www.domain.com/article1/ => blog.domain.com/article1/